# MongoDB - Inserting a document with $type causes exception

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

MongoDB is throwing an error when I try and insert the following document:

```
{
  "dt": "2014-05-13 02:43:01.454",
  "ev": "coredatasaveform",
  "ci": "rQBDXUAbSqy8BP3ZuOXWVg==",
  "mi": "Hw5ySHcJSO+HKxBD1s4zQA==",
  "on": "Company",
  "json": {
    "_id": {
      "$type": "03",
      "$binary": "O1tFU+smDEGo/v/hB1/giw=="
    },
    "_lastmodifieddatelocalutc": "2014-05-13 02:43:01",
    "name": "A company name here",
    "_lastmodifiedonservertime": {
      "$date": 1398876087000
    },
    "_zv": "1.8",
    "_mi": "Hw5ySHcJSO+HKxBD1s4zQA==",
    "sourceofdata": "xxxccc"
  },
  "na": "HPSDbUtilities persistCapturedModelValuesSetWithModel (null)",
  "rc": "1"
}
```

The error looks like this:

```
03:44:02.0421 WriteMongoDocument Exception was :Element name '$type' is not valid because it starts with a '$'.    at MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonWriter.CheckElementName(String name)
   at MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonWriter.WriteName(String name)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonDocumentSerializer.Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, Object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonValueSerializer.Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, Object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonDocumentSerializer.Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, Object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonValueSerializer.Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, Object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonDocumentSerializer.Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, Object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoInsertMessage.AddDocument(BsonBuffer buffer, Type nominalType, Object document)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.InsertOperation.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.InsertBatch(Type nominalType, IEnumerable documents, MongoInsertOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Insert(Type nominalType, Object document, MongoInsertOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Insert(Type nominalType, Object document)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Insert[TNominalType](TNominalType document)
   at Tradeshow.Models.Mongo.WriteMongoLogDocument(String rawJSON, Int32 ix) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Tradeshow\Tradeshow\Models\Mongo.cs:line 665
```

The code looks like this:

```
BsonDocument document = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(rawJSON);
collection.Insert(document);
```

However, if I transpose the "$type" and "$binary" elements of the "_id" element within the "json" element then Mongo is happy for the document to be inserted.  So, this works:

```
{
  "dt": "2014-05-13 02:43:01.454",
  "ev": "coredatasaveform",
  "ci": "rQBDXUAbSqy8BP3ZuOXWVg==",
  "mi": "Hw5ySHcJSO+HKxBD1s4zQA==",
  "on": "Company",
  "json": {
    "_id": {
      "$binary": "O1tFU+smDEGo/v/hB1/giw=="
      ,"$type": "03"
    },
    "_lastmodifieddatelocalutc": "2014-05-13 02:43:01",
    "name": "A company name here",
    "_lastmodifiedonservertime": {
      "$date": 1398876087000
    },
    "_zv": "1.8",
    "_mi": "Hw5ySHcJSO+HKxBD1s4zQA==",
    "sourceofdata": "xxxccc"
  },
  "na": "HPSDbUtilities persistCapturedModelValuesSetWithModel (null)",
  "rc": "1"
}
```

The JSON document is being created by a system slightly outside my control, so getting Mongo to accept the first version is a lot more palatable that having to try to change the format of the JSON.

Can anyone shed any light on why the first version fails but the second works, and how to get the second to work?

I am using the official MongoDB C# driver (v1.8.3.9).

Thanks very much

Comment: Is there a reason you need to have a field named `$type`? I would guess it doesn't like it because there is a keyword [$type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) and no keyword `$binary`. So internally, I would guess, it's scanning for keywords first and ignores keywords for later object fields.

Comment: As shown in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/), `The field names cannot start with the dollar sign ($) character.` But the question is good, how is it working ?

Comment: Are you sure it is working ? I have done the same test within my mongoshell and have the same error for both. Perhaps a bug with the driver... Are you able to do a findOne on your document ?

Comment: An answer was given for why this is so though you may have missed it. It's a feature of the driver which supports the extended JSON syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that this is actually part of the [extended JSON synta](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)x for MongoDB which is actually supported inside the JSON Utils of the C# driver.

As shown [directly in the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#binary) when the fields are presented in the correct order:

```js
"_id": {
  "$binary": "O1tFU+smDEGo/v/hB1/giw==",
  "$type": "03"
}
```

Then the actual value will be translated as a [BinData](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) type of field in the internal BSON representation.

As JSON and therefore BSON maintains the order of key values, the order in which they are presented will cause a problem if these were actually reversed.

So hence the source of your error.

You might look at some preliminary parsing of this data or otherwise find a way to manipulate the chunk before directly passing that other to the JSON utils functions for parsing that directly into BSON.

Just FYI, you can even see this demonstrated in the [unit tests](https://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp/blob/6397a0f032f24227894afa6ec37e92dd18dd0b3f/source/MongoDB.Tests/UnitTests/Util/TestJsonUtils.cs#L138) for the driver source.